# Counter doesn't get incremented if the for loop contains a wild card character * in windows batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wildcard

Would really appreciate any help provided on the below issue. I have a windows batch script that takes  5 command line arguments and I need to perform a count within the script to ensure that 5 parameters have been entered. The script is called as mentioned below. Either 1st, 2nd or 3rd parameter can be mentioned with wildcard. I have used the first.

**returnlist.bat "sh*" "" "" "domainroot" "C:\tmp\outfile.txt"**

I use the following block of code to evaluate the counter

```
set /A argC=0
for %%x in (%*) do Set /A argC+=1
echo %argC%
```

In this case, the count returned is 4 instead of 5 and script fails as 5 arguments are expected. However, if we do not use the * in the command line parameters, then we are returned the correct count of 5.

Hence I changed the code to

```
Set /A argC=0
Set argStr=%*

:SplitParams
if "!argStr!" NEQ "" (
        for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%i in ("!argStr!") do (
                Set myArr[!argC!]=%%i
                Set /A argC+=1
                Set argStr=%%j
                goto :SplitParams
        )
)
```

This handles the wildcard character and returns a count of 5 when * is included. 
However, if any of the command line parameters have a space in them

**Eg. returnlist.bat "test sh*" "" "" "domainroot" "C:\tmp\outfile.txt"**

then the first argument is treated as 2 parameters and hence the count returned is 6 instead of 5 which again causes the script to fail as only 5 arguments are expected.

Would highly appreciate any help provided on this issue. I need to be able to specify wildcard characters and space could also be present in the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If your only question is regarding counting of arguments... do you really need to count them? How about this?

```
if "%~5"=="" echo.*** ERROR *** Not enough arguments & pause & goto :eof
```

I also notice that you are attempting to use delayed expansion, but have not enabled it. Is there additional code?

Comment: Yes, this is how I would do it. However, it only works for up to 9 expected arguments. Beyond that the values must be saved and SHIFT employed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you place an argument with a wild-card in a `for` command the wild-card is always expanded. You should get the parameters the old way, via `shift` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set argC=0
:SplitParams
   set /A argC+=1
   set myArr[%argC%]=%1
   shift
if defined myArr[%argC%] goto SplitParams

set /A argC-=1
echo Number of params: %argC%
for /L %%i in (1,1,%argC%) do echo %%i - !myArr[%%i]!
```

For example:

```
C:\> returnlist.bat "test sh*" "" "" "domainroot" "C:\tmp\outfile.txt"
Number of params: 5
1 - "test sh*"
2 - ""
3 - ""
4 - "domainroot"
5 - "C:\tmp\outfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q27537815.txt) DO (
 CALL :returnlist %%a
)

GOTO :EOF

:returnlist
:: remove variables starting arg
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set arg 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET /a argcount=0
SET "empty="
SET "wildcards="
:argloop
SET "arg=%1"
IF NOT DEFINED arg GOTO report

SET /a argcount+=1
SET "arg=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED arg SET empty=%empty% %argcount%&shift&GOTO argloop
SET "arg%argcount%=%~1"
ECHO %arg%|FIND "*" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "wildcards=%wildcards% %argcount%
SHIFT
GOTO argloop

:report 
ECHO %argcount% arguments IN %*
IF DEFINED empty ECHO arguments%empty% are empty
IF DEFINED wildcards ECHO arguments%wildcards% contain wildcards
SET arg
GOTO :eof
```

This demonstration with this data file `q27537815.txt`

```
"only one parameter"
"two" "but who's counting"
"now three" "*" "#2 is asterisk"
"4" "" "*" "four-empty-star-thisstring"
"5" "*" "" "*" "five - two asterisks, middle empty"
"6" "too" "many" "parameters" "this" "time"
"5" "*" "*" "*" "five - three asterisks"
5 * ""  * five-two-asterisks-middle-empty
6 too many parameters this time
```

Yielded this report

```
1 arguments IN "only one parameter"
arg1=only one parameter
argcount=1
2 arguments IN "two" "but who's counting"
arg1=two
arg2=but who's counting
argcount=2
3 arguments IN "now three" "*" "#2 is asterisk"
arguments 2 contain wildcards
arg1=now three
arg2=*
arg3=#2 is asterisk
argcount=3
4 arguments IN "4" "" "*" "four-empty-star-thisstring"
arguments 2 are empty
arguments 3 contain wildcards
arg1=4
arg3=*
arg4=four-empty-star-thisstring
argcount=4
5 arguments IN "5" "*" "" "*" "five - two asterisks, middle empty"
arguments 3 are empty
arguments 2 4 contain wildcards
arg1=5
arg2=*
arg4=*
arg5=five - two asterisks, middle empty
argcount=5
6 arguments IN "6" "too" "many" "parameters" "this" "time"
arg1=6
arg2=too
arg3=many
arg4=parameters
arg5=this
arg6=time
argcount=6
5 arguments IN "5" "*" "*" "*" "five - three asterisks"
arguments 2 3 4 contain wildcards
arg1=5
arg2=*
arg3=*
arg4=*
arg5=five - three asterisks
argcount=5
5 arguments IN 5 * ""  * five-two-asterisks-middle-empty
arguments 3 are empty
arguments 2 4 contain wildcards
arg1=5
arg2=*
arg4=*
arg5=five-two-asterisks-middle-empty
argcount=5
6 arguments IN 6 too many parameters this time
arg1=6
arg2=too
arg3=many
arg4=parameters
arg5=this
arg6=time
argcount=6
```

Which should deliver your counts appropriately.